# python-ajax prevent view source response data

Tags: python, ajax, flask

i'm coding python using flask framework.
The data response from server keep showing up when i use "view-source" from browsers.

html:

```
$('li.channel, div.channel-in-top').on('click', function(e){
  $.getJSON($(this).find('a').attr('href'), function(data){
    ...
  }
}
```

server code for response:

```
if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
  return current_app.response_class(json.dumps(c), mimetype='application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

c is an array of some data.
I've tried return only c, jsonify(c)
Every time when i use view-source from browser (chrome, firefox), it shows the whole data c that is return.

I've visited some website using ajax (not python thou) and see that before or after trigger ajax, view-source can just see the html as usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the real problem.
It's about the html5' history.pushState
The ajax of flask-Python itself is doing fine